# Artifactory can't resolve helm charts

Tags: artifactory

i am facing issue sometime when i need to deploy my apps usign helm charts:
the update of repository is getting timed out and we can't deploy.
in the logs i see:

```
2-06-14T09:33:53.151Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [185bdda5673ce024] [.AsyncWorkQueueServiceImpl:275] [WorkQueueJob        ] - Executing Helm Virtual Metadata stuck tasks: 4651
2022-06-14T09:33:53.151Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [185bdda5673ce024] [.AsyncWorkQueueServiceImpl:275] [WorkQueueJob        ] - Executing Docker Catalog Index stuck tasks: 23
2022-06-14T09:33:53.152Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [185bdda5673ce024] [.AsyncWorkQueueServiceImpl:275] [WorkQueueJob        ] - Executing Helm Metadata stuck tasks: 2
2022-06-14T09:33:53.152Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [185bdda5673ce024] [.AsyncWorkQueueServiceImpl:275] [WorkQueueJob        ] - Executing Maven Metadata stuck tasks: 243
2022-06-14T09:33:53.152Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [185bdda5673ce024] [.AsyncWorkQueueServiceImpl:275] [WorkQueueJob        ] - Executing Conan Metadata stuck tasks: 272
2022-06-14T09:33:53.152Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [185bdda5673ce024] [.AsyncWorkQueueServiceImpl:275] [WorkQueueJob        ] - Executing Npm Metadata stuck tasks: 1
2022-06-14T09:33:53.313Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [9da4cfb83d1da2c5] [.r.ArtifactoryResponseBase:174] [tp-nio-8081-exec-159] - Client Closed Request 499: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
2022-06-14T09:33:58.153Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d095d20ce78b7e4b] [.AsyncWorkQueueServiceImpl:275] [WorkQueueJob        ] - Executing Helm Virtual Metadata stuck tasks: 4652
2022-06-14T09:33:58.153Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d095d20ce78b7e4b] [.AsyncWorkQueueServiceImpl:275] [WorkQueueJob        ] - Executing Docker Catalog Index stuck tasks: 23
2022-06-14T09:33:58.153Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d095d20ce78b7e4b] [.AsyncWorkQueueServiceImpl:275] [WorkQueueJob        ] - Executing Helm Metadata stuck tasks: 2
2022-06-14T09:33:58.153Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [d095d20ce78b7e4b] [.AsyncWorkQueueServiceImpl:275] [WorkQueueJob        ] - Executing Maven Metadata stuck tasks: 243
```

Version used: **7.38.10 rev 73810900**
A restart of Artifactory fixes the issue however this is really inconvenient.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any memory or cpu intensive process are running on the host where the artifactory is hosted. I have the same problem with Artifactory 7.37.xx version and I found that one of our artifactory replication process was using a lot of resources which lead to these stuck messages on helm indexes, inturn causing helm repo add and update to mostly fail and there by helm install.